# ArcPad not recording attribute info on Junos

Tags: arcpad, trimble, juno

I have some Juno SBs and 3B which are running ArcPad version 10.2.  We run a custom Applet and these units will record points and let the user fill in the attribute information however the attribute data is not saved to the table, the fields are blank.  We are successfully running this Applet on dozens of other Junos with identical specs with no issues.  We have tried a hard reset and restoring factory settings, including uninstalling and reinstalling ArcPad, with no change. Any ideas on what would cause this issue that would not be fixed by a factory reset?

Comment: Two questions: (1) What information is not being captured?  Is this text and numeric attributes, etc. (2) Is ArcPad getting positions from the Juno internal receiver?

Answer (score 0):

I would check where the project data is being stored check that it can write to SD card if that's the location. If all is ok I would factory reset the device.